# Linux daemon set /proc/

Tags: c++, linux, client, daemon, proc

I once wrote a simple daemon in bash - also sets the values in /proc/*. For example,

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

I want to rewrite in C + + and share - but how to use the /proc/* in C++? as the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember: on Unix, everything is a file (well, granted, *almost* everything).

Your current shell code actually means: write the value 50 (`echo 50`) **into the file** (`redirection operator >`) which name follows (`/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`).

---

In C++, just open `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` as a file and read/write to it using whatever method you prefer: C++ `fstream`, C `fopen/fread/fwrite`, ...

Example with `fstream` (namely `ofstream` since we're only writing to it):

```
std::ofstream file("/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness");
if (!file.is_open())
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not open the file");
file << 50;
file.close();
```

Comment: Almost everything is almost like a file.  :)

Comment: @Duck: haha, couldn't have said it better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Code sample:

```
int val = 50;

FILE *f = fopen("/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness", "w");
if (!f)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Huh, couldn't open /sys/class ... ");
   exit(1);
}
fprintf(f, "%d", val);
fclose(f);
```